# flutter Firebase Animated List view how to pass data to detail screen

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-navigation

Data Retrieved on the first screen in Animated listview  and want to Navigate the clicked item detail screen and want to  know complete detail how to pass values on the second screen widgets

Here is the Code:

Data Retrieved from Firebase real-time database

1st Screen:

```dart
 FirebaseAnimatedList(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      defaultChild: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      query: reference,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
          Animation<double> animation, int index) {
        Map mydata = snapshot.value;
        mydata['key'] = snapshot.key;

        return InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            {
              //// how to Navigate
            }
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.black87,
              child: FadeInImage(
                image: NetworkImage(mydata['image']),
                placeholder: AssetImage("assets/images/placeholder.png"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    )
```

How to pass and assign a value on Second screen widgets

Second Screen

```dart
class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 250,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
        image: DecorationImage(
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          image: NetworkImage(// How to pass  ),
              ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate using [Navigator.push](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/push.html) and the next screen to the method.

And in order to send the data, you can pass the data through the constructor to the second widget while navigating.

**Solution**:

1. Update your `SecondScreen` widget to this:

```dart
class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  const SecondScreen({Key? key, required this.url}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 250,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
        image: DecorationImage(
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          image: NetworkImage(widget.url),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*It adds the `url` parameter to the `SecondScreen` widget's constructor and it retrieves it in the `State` by using the `widget.url`.*

2. Update the `onTap` of the `InkWell` to this:

```dart
  onTap: () {
            {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => SecondScreen(
                    url: mydata['image'],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
```

*It passes the data to the `SecondWidget` using it's `url` parameter.*

---

Check out [Send data to a new screen](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data)
for more.